# Posting data to a dropwizard resource?

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

I am trying to establish how I might post data to my dropwizard resource.

Say for example I have the following resource :

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("/update/{id}")
public int updateRecord(    @PathParam("id") int id) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException

// Logic here I guess?!

// Returning 0 to kill the error regarding not returning antyhing in my IDE.
return 0;
}
```

now I would like to be able to do a jquery post, such as :

$.post("http://localhost:8080/update/1/", jsonUpdateString);

for the record "jsonUpdateString" is a stringified JSON array - I already know how to map that to a java data structure, as I have done it hardcoded before - I just need to know what I need to add to my resource to actually use "jsonUpdateString" in my java side.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
static class Entity {
  @JsonProperty String name;
}

@POST
@Timed
@Path("update/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public int updateRecord(@PathParam("id") int id, List<Entity> entities) {
  // Do something with entities...
  return 0;
}
```

Which you can test with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '[{"name":"foo"}]' http://localhost:8080/update/1
```

A few things:

- If your method has one unannotated argument (`entities`, in this case) Jersey will attempt to map the request entity to this object.
- Let Jersey / Jackson do the JSON conversion for you (see `Entity`).
- Make sure that your JQuery client is setting the request header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: Thanks - but when I do that I get an error : "405" Any ideas how I might fix?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path? 405 is "method not allowed" - so either it sounds like the wrong type of request is being sent to the server.